# UWP Background Task Timer not firing

Tags: c#, background, uwp

I am currently developing an app with a background task that should be fired at a **time that is set by the user**. The user for example selects '01:45 PM', the app is calculating the minutes from now to that time and **registers a background task** with a timetrigger. Unfortunately the background task isn't firing at all. Sometimes it just fired after I started my computer. I am thankful for any advice as I can't solve this problem since one week.

I already **debugged** the background task by starting it via VisualStudio, so the problem isn't in the BackgroundTask.cs-file.

Here is my code:

- **Register the background task:**

  ```
  //I set the time to 15 minutes to see if this would work. It didn't...
  var trigger = new TimeTrigger(15, true);
  BackgroundTaskHelper.RegisterBackgroundTask("BackgroundTask.BackgroundTask", "BackgroundTask", trigger, null);
  ```
- **Method to register the background task:**

  ```
  public static async void RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskEntryPoint, string taskName, IBackgroundTrigger trigger, IBackgroundCondition condition)
  {
      foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
      {
          if (cur.Value.Name == taskName)
          {
              cur.Value.Unregister(true);
          }
      }            
      var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
      builder.Name = taskName;
      builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
      builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

      if (condition != null)
      {
          builder.AddCondition(condition);
      }

      await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
      var task = builder.Register();
  }
  ```
- **Package.appxmanifest**
  [Package.appxmanifest, Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DdBa.png)

**Thank you for any help!**

Comment: There can be many issues with that. Two things that come into my mind that are issues very often: How long does the Background Task run (more than 30 seconds is an issue with standard BGTask) and second: How high is the CPU usage for this Task and how high was the CPU usage, when it should run? Also this might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/debug-a-background-task

Comment: Currently it is just sending one toast notification so the duration is less than 30 seconds and the cpu usage is low.

Comment: And the CPU usage while it is firing? Because sometimes a Task will not fire, if if the host machine has a high CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new [TimeTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.TimeTrigger). The second parameter, OneShot, specifies whether the background task will run only once or keep running periodically. If OneShot is set to true, the first parameter (FreshnessTime) specifies the number of minutes to wait before scheduling the background task. If OneShot is set to false, FreshnessTime specifies the frequency at which the [background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-) will run.

If FreshnessTime is set to 15 minutes and OneShot is true, the task will be scheduled to run once starting between 15 and 30 minutes from the time it is registered. If it is set to 25 minutes and OneShot is true, the task will be scheduled to run once starting between 25 and 40 minutes from the time it is registered.

So the `TimeTrigger` is not suit for your scenario. In Windows 10 UWP, alarms are simply Toast notifications with the “alarm” scenario. And to make an alarm appear at a specific time, you could use a scheduled Toast notification.

The following code is how to Schedule the alarm to appear at a certain time. Details please reference [Quickstart: Sending an alarm in Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/09/30/quickstart-sending-an-alarm-in-windows-10/). The accompanying [sample application](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/quickstart-alarms) is a simple quickstart-alarms application.

```
DateTime alarmTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

// Only schedule notifications in the future
// Adding a scheduled notification with a time in the past
// will throw an exception.
if (alarmTime > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5))
{
    // Generate the toast content (from previous steps)
    ToastContent toastContent = GenerateToastContent();

    // Create the scheduled notification
    var scheduledNotif = new ScheduledToastNotification(
        toastContent.GetXml(), // Content of the toast
        alarmTime // Time we want the toast to appear at
        );

    // And add it to the schedule
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(scheduledNotif);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very interesting! Is there any possibility to get the content after the scheduled time? I want to check a webpages content at the scheduled time and send a toast notification with parts of this webpage. Is there any way to get the content dynamically at this time?